# Index out of range in basic while loop

Tags: ios, swift, while-loop, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm parsing HTML and reformatting images to fit nicely. For some reason, where I have multiple images to parse, I'm going out of range and I can't figure out why for the life of me.

When imgArray.count is >1 I'm looping through using a standard while loop with an incrementing counter.

In one example, imgArray count was 3 and i was 3, but my loop went out of range, though I could see the appropriate values in multImgArray up to multImgArray[2]

As you can see, I'm decrementing 1 within the array position to keep the count integer and array position in sync

```
  if image {
    var imgArray = image.components(separatedBy: "style=")
    imgArray.removeFirst() //to remove unused portion of html

    var newImgArray = [String]()
    var multImgArray = [[String]]()

    if imgArray.isEmpty == false {
      if imgArray.count == 1 {
        newImgArray = imgArray[0].components(separatedBy: ">")
      } else {            
        var i = 0
        while i < imgArray.count {
          i+=1
          multImgArray.append(imgArray[i-1].components(separatedBy: ">"))
        }
      }
```

Edit:

Original HTML Snippet

```
<p style="width:1000pt">
```

After the loop, I should have the original snippet for each image in an array which I do. But the loop goes out of range as if Xcode is trying to append an array position that isn't there.

Eventual Expected Output (replace step not shown here but added for clarification as per others request):

```
<p style="max-width:\(max-width)pt"> //where max-width is defined elsewhere as self.view.frame.width - 50
```

Comment: Why don't you use some framework for html parsing?

Comment: I'm still learning. I learn the hard way ;)

Comment: What is the purpose of removeFirst?

Comment: If I don't use removeFirst() an empty string is placed at the [0] position leaving me to handle it later

Comment: Have you tried creating an empty array? `var array = [String]()` or `var array = [[String]]()`

Comment: Thanks, probably what I used to do... I'm coming back from a 6 month break lol

Comment: Can you add an example or two of what the variable `image` is to start with here, to help understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm appending one array to another separating by a string in a while loop. Not sure what more you need. It's a crapton of HTML

Comment: Why are you using a while-loop? Use a forin-loop... much safer. `for value in imgArray {
    multImgArray.append(value.components(separatedBy: ">"))
}`

Comment: As others have said, it's a bit hard to identify what you're trying to do here. It would be better if you edit your answer to include some snippets of the HTML you're parsing, the output you're expecting (or at least the state of the arrays after this code has executed) and the actual error message you're seeing. Are you certain that the problem is that `while` loop, and not something else?

Comment: By popular demand, edited question to show html snippet, output after this step, and eventual expected output

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues with empty strings - you can remove them before processing an array. For example, you can use some extension:

```
extension Array where Element == String {

    func filterEmpty() -> [String] {
        return filter({ !$0.isEmpty })
    }
}
```

And later use it this way:

```
let imgArray = image.components(separatedBy: "style=").filterEmpty()
```

Also, your loop is a bit confusing. You can do it without the loop. For example:

```
let image = "style=A>style=B>Bstyle=C>C"
var imgArray = image.components(separatedBy: "style=").filterEmpty()
var newImgArray = [String]()
var multImgArray = [[String]]()
switch imgArray.count {
case 2...:
    multImgArray = imgArray.map({ $0.components(separatedBy: ">").filterEmpty() })
case 1:
    newImgArray = imgArray[0].components(separatedBy: ">").filterEmpty()
default:
    break
}
```

So, it might solve loop issues. Hope it helps

P.S. Or even this way:

```
let image = "style=A>style=B>Bstyle=C>C"
let imgArray = image.nonEmptyComponents(separatedBy: "style=")
let newImgArray = imgArray.first?.nonEmptyComponents(separatedBy: ">") ?? []
let multImgArray = imgArray.map({ $0.nonEmptyComponents(separatedBy: ">") })

extension Array where Element == String {

    func filterEmpty() -> [String] {
        return filter({ !$0.isEmpty })
    }
}

extension String {

    func nonEmptyComponents(separatedBy string: String) -> [String] {
        return components(separatedBy: string).filterEmpty()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I took @iWheelBuy advice and created empty arrays instead. It didn't affect the issue with the loop, but it's very clean. strArray = [String]() instead of strArray = String[""]